# JSON-RPC Message error when starting geth node or testrpc

Tags: json, json-rpc, ethereum, private-network

I am trying to create a private network so that I can start testing my Solidity code. However, when starting the a geth private network with `geth --rpc` but I then run into an error for an invalid response. `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}` when checking localhost:8545.

I don't think it matters, but my genesis.json file is

```
 {
"nonce": "0x0000000000000042",     "timestamp": "0x0",
"parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"extraData": "0x0",     "gasLimit": "0x8000000",     "difficulty": "0x400",
"mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333",     "alloc": {     }}
```

I have also tried creating a test network with testrpc with just the command `testrpc` but here the localhost:8545 returns a parsing error `{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": null, "error": {"message": "Parse error", "code": -32700}}`.

What is the JSON that I am sending because it seems to be incorrectly written?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what exactly you are trying, but the JSON RPC endpoint of geth requires a JSON command, for instance try to query the web3 version with the following request:

```
{
  "method": "web3_clientVersion",
  "params": []
}
```

It complains because you do not provide any request, i.e., running a plain testrpc command.

But inbetween the lines I read that you are *testing* your solidity code. Have you had a look at the wonderful [browser solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/)?